# How to convert multiple files as zip in nodejs?

Tags: node.js

Here my code:

So someone help how to dowload the files as a zip folder

```
exports.downloadAllFiles = function(req,res){
    demodb.findOne({ guid: req.params.id }, function(err, data) { 
        if (err) {
            console.log("Error in finding case....");
            res.json(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, {});
        } else {
            if(data){
                // Here multiple files are contained in the data array
                //So I need to download the files into a zip folder
            }
        }
    })
    };
```

Comment: [adm-zip](https://www.npmjs.com/package/adm-zip) or [node-zip](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-zip) can help you with that ;)

Comment: Looksl like you are using mongoDB - can you elaborate on what data you are getting? Is it an array of URL's like ["https://www.foo.com/bar/barfood.pdf", "https://www.bar.com/foo/barrfoot.doc", ".." , ".."] that you wish to download and then zip?

Answer (score 3):

You can do this using [ADM-ZIP](https://github.com/cthackers/adm-zip)

```
    const zip=require('adm-zip');
    var zipper = new zip();
    zipper.addLocalFile('1.csv');
    zipper.addLocalFile('2.csv');
    zipper.addLocalFile('3.csv');
    zipper.writeZip("123.zip");
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a small example of adm-zip on how to add files directly, from local directory and buffer:

```
// creating archives
var zip = new AdmZip();

// add file directly
zip.addFile("test.txt", new Buffer("inner content of the file"), "entry comment goes here");
// add local file
zip.addLocalFile("/home/me/some_picture.png");
// get everything as a buffer
var willSendthis = zip.toBuffer();
// or write everything to disk
zip.writeZip(/*target file name*/"/home/me/files.zip");
```

In your case you can add files in a for loop iterating through the array and adding a file in each recursion.

```
exports.downloadAllFiles = function(req,res){
demodb.findOne({ guid: req.params.id }, function(err, data) { 
    if (err) {
        console.log("Error in finding case....");
        res.json(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, {});
    } else {
        if(data){
            // for loop goes here:
            for(var i =0; i<data.length; i++){
              // add the files to zip
            }                
        }
    }
})
};
```

Comment: @Prakash Sure, give me a sec or two - I need to finish deploying some stuff for work and then update my answer ;)

Comment: Yah...please take your time and thank you so much @iLuvLogix

Comment: regarding my question in the comments of your question - can u confirm that?

Answer (score 0):

```
var AdmZip = require('adm-zip');
    var zip = new AdmZip();
    var fs=require('fs-extra');
    let arr = ['AKTU.pdf', 'test1.pdf']
    for(let i = 0 ;i<arr.length ;i++){
      zip.addLocalFile(`./createZip/${arr[i]}`); //local path
    }
    zip.writeZip("./files.zip");
```

You can use this code to add multiple files in a zip.